# singleton client connector

Tags: java, networking, connection

Picture that you have a chat program where you want to send and recive data to & from the server.  would it be smart to turn the clients connection into a singleton? or will this ruin the data stream.

my example of a client singleton:

```
public class Client {
    private static Client client;
    private final int portNumber = 7070;
    private Socket socket;
    private Client(){
        connect();

    }
    public static synchronized Client getClient(){
        if (client == null) {
            client = new Client();
        }
        return client;
    }

    public void connect(){

        try {
            InetAddress adr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            socket = new Socket(adr, portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- singletons are very inflexible. If you want to implement load-balancing or connection pooling in the future, your hands are tied. Only one connection is allowed. And what about reconnecting? How do you get rid of old connection and create a new one?
- connecting (or any operation that has side-effects) inside a constructor is not a good practice. Imagine unit-testing this class

So I don't advice singleton connection object. Instead have a `ClientConnections` manager class with `Client connect()` method. This manager class keeps track of all opened connections, can cache them, close unused, test periodically, etc. `ClientConnections` is a better candidate for singleton.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: it might sound like that from my description, but not really. `ClientConnections` is a class to manage connections on the client side. Think from more global perspective, when one client application needs more than one connection, wants to reconnect, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sense to use singleton clients if you dont want more than one connection per client. This should be fine for most cases, except when you want to support sending multiple files simultaneously.